# How to detect if a button is in a desired area in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I detect if a button is in a desired area
I have used `if( button.frame.orgin.x == area.framee.orgin.x){
if (button.frame.orgin.y == area.frame.orgin.y )`}; 
The Problem with this code is that it is very exact so it is hard to match up the button with the label. So I would like to know how to detect if a button is inside a desired area. And how to make the area bigger than the button. Thanks In advance

Comment: By "desired area" do you mean some rectangle?  Use CGRectIntersectsRect, but remember to do so with the button's frame in the coordinate system of the button's superview.

Comment: Yes when the button enters the rectangle I want a line of code to run.

Comment: great.  either answer given below (using intersection, not contains) should work for you.  pls pick the best one and mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably `CGRectContainsRect()` which would work something like:

```
if(CGRectContainsRect(someRect, button.frame))
{
//Button is in area.
}
```

To expand the rect you can use `CGRectInset()`, passing negative values to increase the frame size by that amount. This function will maintain the center of the original rect.

```
CGRect newRect = CGRectInset (smallRect, -10.0f, -10.0f);
```

You can read more about CGGeometry functions in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GCRectContainsRect(frame1, frame2);` to see if an object is contained within another object. Or use `CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1, frame2);` to see if the rects overlap at all.